# Can command line linking of app specify @executable_path for .dylib

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, dylib

Other than using the install_name_tool to CHANGE the search paths after linking, or setting the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, is there a command line linker directive that will allow the specification of the .dylib to be @executable_path?  We want to put all our required .dylib files inside the app bundle.

Of course, if the launched executable could temporarily set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH immediately upon launch, that would also work.

The ultimate goal here is to allow an automated makefile-driven build process to insure that the required dynamic libraries can be gathered and placed in the bundle so the executable application can find them (using @executable_path).

NOTE: @rpath isn't an option -- the frameworks / dylibs we require aren't built by us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your options are:

- Specify `-install_name <name>` when linking the libraries themselves. (Not when linking the executable against the libraries). I gather from your "NOTE:" that this isn't possible.
- Use `install_name_tool -id <name>` to change the install names of the libraries before you link the executable against them. That way, the executable will incorporate the right references to them. To be completely safe, the libraries should have been linked with `-headerpad_max_install_names`.
- Use `install_name_tool -change <old> <new>` on the executable after you have linked it, which is what you're seeking an alternative to. Again, to be safe, the executable should have been linked with `-headerpad_max_install_names`.

Unfortunately, those are your only options.

If your goal is to automate the build, it's very possible to automate the changing of the references to the libraries in the executable. We use a script like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

exit if ("$ENV{'ACTION'}" ne "build");

my $fullpath = "$ENV{'TARGET_BUILD_DIR'}/$ENV{'EXECUTABLE_PATH'}";

open(my $otool, "otool -L '$fullpath' |") || die "otool: $fullpath: $!";

# The first line of otool output is the file name echoed.  Consume that.
my $file_echo = <$otool>;

# Process the lines listing dependent libraries
while (my $lib_line = <$otool>)
{
    if ($lib_line =~ m%[[:blank:]]+(.*/([^/]*\.dylib))[[:blank:]]+\(compatibility version%)
    {
        my $lib_orig_path = $1;
        my $lib_subpath = $2;

        my $command = "install_name_tool -change '$lib_orig_path' '\@executable_path/../Frameworks/$lib_subpath' '$fullpath'";
        print "$command\n";
        system($command) == 0 or die "system:install_name_tool:$fullpath: $!";
    }
}

open(my $timestamp_file, ">", "$ENV{'DERIVED_FILE_DIR'}/fixup_executable_lib_deps.timestamp") or die "open: $!";
print $timestamp_file time;
close($timestamp_file) or die "close: $!";

exit;
```

The script is designed to be used in a Run Script build phase of an Xcode project, so it depends on environment variables that Xcode sets, but you can change that to use command-line arguments easily enough.

The timestamp file is used as an output for the Run Script build phase so Xcode can know when it doesn't need to be re-run. The inputs are the executable and this script file itself. You can map those to make file targets.

Comment: Ken, in this context, would it ever make sense to use @loader_path instead of @executable_path?

Comment: It depends on the situation. In this case, you're changing the references from the executable to the libraries that it immediately depends on. So, the loader is the executable and `@loader_path` is the same as `@executable_path`. If the libraries depend on each other, you also have to change the references between them. If all of the libraries are in the same place in the app bundle, those references can be relative to `@loader_path` pretty simply. That also works if the libraries are used by multiple executables that are located in different places.

Answer (score 1):

Ken Thomases' answer is detailed and accurate, however there is ONE other option, and it appears to be a good one:

[Macdylibbundler:](https://github.com/auriamg/macdylibbundler) (from the web site):  "dylibbundler is a small command-line program that aims to make bundling .dylibs as easy as possible. It automatically determines which dylibs are needed by your program, copies these libraries inside the app bundle, and fixes both them and the executable to be ready for distribution... all this with a single command on the teminal! It will also work if your program uses plug-ins that have dependencies too.